# Accepting Friend Requests functionality in Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to make the friend request functionality work, I am through with the sending and receiving requests part but I am stuck as to how to update the friends data collection for a specific user as the user accepts a friend request.

I want this to happen :

```
Friends (collection)
    userID (document) 
        list of friends (their uid's)
        .
        .    
        .    
        .
```

And the list of friends gets appended with a new uid if the user accepts a new request.

Here is a screenshot of my db:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to first focus on how you are going to structure your data. If you want to keep 'Friends' collection to store the information about the friendship of a user, you need to first figure out what kind of queries you will be issuing on that collection.
Primarily you will need:
 1. Is user A friends with User B and vice versa. 
 2. List of all users A is friends with.

Your current structure solves both the cases, but try to see if you can improve/optimize it for other use cases. I would leave that to you but would leave you with a hint. You are modeling a "has many" relation through a table, an efficient way would be to store a "friendship" information (user1, user2)

**Answer to the original question starts here**
You need to add a new key/value pair in the Friends collection for a given key.

```
let newRelation = {};
newRelation[friendUID] = {date: new Date().getTime()} // store whatever info you need to store here.
firestore.collection("friends").doc(uid).update(newRelation) // Udpdate the user document to add friendship
```

You also need to update the "friendship" for the friend, just reverse the keys for that.